# undefined reference to `CORBA::ValueBase::ValueBase()' , how can I solve it? (which library to use in omniORB)

Tags: c++, corba, omniorb

I am using omniORB for CORBA in C++.

when I used omniidl, compiler to generate stub and skeleton files for an idl file, auto generated code inherits the given class from public  `::CORBA::ValueBase`.

During compilation I am getting an error of undefined constructor & destructor for `::CORBA::ValueBase`.

As it is a standard file I can't define constructor & destructor for it. Can anybody please let me know which library contains the definations or how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you linking with the files that the omniidl translator created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libomniDynamic4 contains the definition  of ::CORBA::ValueBase, so including the library in linking path solves the linking errors and application compiles successfully.